# SSRS count number of time value exists in data set - countifs equivalent

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am trying to carry out a data quality check in SSRS where by I am counting the number of times a string exists in a dataset to check for duplicate values.

This is one of many checks so I would like to run out a single dataset to cover all the checks. Below outlines what I would like to produce...

```
╔══════════════╦═══════╗
║ Check Column ║ Count ║
╠══════════════╬═══════╣
║ A1           ║     1 ║
║ B2           ║     2 ║
║ C1           ║     1 ║
║ B2           ║     2 ║
║ C2           ║     3 ║
║ C2           ║     3 ║
║ A2           ║     1 ║
║ C2           ║     3 ║
╚══════════════╩═══════╝
```

However the added complication is that I need to carry this out as a calculated field rather than on a tablix as only the count of the duplicates is needed (5 in the table above).

I have carried out a testbed of this in Excel and the `countif` function covers this simply enough and gives me the table of data I need but the report should be doing all this work when it is run from a scheduled.

Any ideas on this - happy with a VBA script to use but I can not find anything on the internet on this.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried using the `=count(iif(condition,true,false))` pattern in the expression?

Answer (score 0):

This is the altnerative: =SUM(Iif(Fields!ColumnCheck.Value="SomeString",1,0).

Comment: The problem is that the "SomeString" needs to be dynamic - if this was in Excel it would be looking like counfif($A:$A, A1) and therefore check all the rows based on the value of the row.